# Can we use White's reality check to compare two Sharpe ratios?

Tags: time-series, sharpe-ratio, data-mining

I read a paper from [Ledoit and Wolf](http://www.ledoit.net/jef_2008pdf.pdf) that proposes a method to compare two Sharpe ratios and a paper from [White](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/718/White2000.pdf) that proposes a method to compare $n$ trading rules.

My question is: Can we use White's method to compare two Sharpe ratios? I prefer this method because it's computationally simpler.

Comment: Did you see the [source code](http://www.econ.uzh.ch/faculty/wolf/publications.html#9) provided by one of the authors of the Ledoit and Wolf paper?

Comment: Yes i see but there is no kernel estimation for the reality check that i have already code

Comment: The point of White is to adjust for multiplicity. Why use it to compare only two Sharpe ratios? Or maybe you want to use it for $n >> 2$ Sharpe ratios?

Comment: WRC is covered by a patent for at least 5 more years, so perhaps the answer is _no_. In the meantime, the Leung & Wong test following Jobson & Korkie's asymptotic expansion is probably just fine for comparing multiple Sharpes.

Comment: @steveo'america What is your source for asserting White's Reality Check is under patent? It's a mathematical equation that would be, to my knowledge, un-patentable. Also, there are open source implementations of it readily available in MatLab, R, Python, and Julia. I wrote the Julia implementation. OP: The Reality Check almost always underperforms the SPA test, which in turn underperforms tests proposed in some recent publications. Further, as James said, for only two ratios, you should just use a standard Diebold-Mariano test, since these other methods are explicitly for $n > 2$.

Comment: @ColinTBowers apparently it _was_ under patent until Jan 2017, as a simple google search would have revealed: https://patents.google.com/patent/US5893069A/en?oq=5893069 . And yes, Hansen's loglog trick is certainly an improvement on WRC. Can I ask what the "tests proposed in some recent publications" are?

Comment: @steveo'america Not all google searches are created equal. I did try one before posting, and that page didn't come up. Thank you for the reference though. I think this is fascinating. A court case attempting to enforce the patent would have been very interesting to see! They're claiming the algorithm is patentable, which seems pretty dubious given it's just a (somewhat complex) application of a dependent bootstrap, and a corollary of prior art is not patentable. The key insight of the paper wasn't the algorithm, but the proof that a bootstrap was applicable in that situation!

Comment: @steveo'america Regarding other tests, the are variations on the SPA theme. See Hsu, Hsu, Kuan (2010) "Testing the predictive ability of technical analysis using a new stepwise test without data snooping bias", and Hsu, Kuan, Yen (2014) "A Generalized Stepwise Procedure with Improved Power for Multiple Inequalities Testing". I think there is another one but can't seem to remember what to search for now...

Comment: ah, thanks. I only recalled White's patent because I remember feeling subversive when implementing it. I too reflexively doubt patentability of 'obvious' uses of known methods, but I also worked for a company that lost +500M in a patent case for using Kalman Filters (!).  A recent survey of several methods for MHT correction on Sharpe is [Pav, 2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.00573). Again, none of these are required for $n=2$ strategies.

Comment: @steveo'america Wow I'm obviously somewhat naive about all this. You would think you'd be safe to implement something that has been in the textbooks for close to 50 years. I did just google "kalman filter under patent" and there were a *lot* of hits... Thanks for the reference. Page 4 looks like a multivariate implementation of what I put in my answer below for the case of $n = 2$.

Comment: @ColinTBowers Yes, the CLT/Delta method analysis was proposed by Jobson & Korkie, later turned into F-test by Leung & Wong, and a $\chi^2$ test by Wright et al.

Answer (score 2):

As James has pointed out in the comments, White's Reality Check is specifically designed to control the family-wise error rate given $k > 2$ statistics. The theory does not depend on $k$ asymptotics, so there is nothing invalid about using White's Reality Check for $2$ statistics, but in practice there would be little point to doing this. Further, as stevo`america points out above, the Reality check had a patent on it until two years ago - whether it would be enforced in a court case though is another question entirely...

In particular, for $k=2$, it is fairly straightforward to construct a simple statistical test for the difference in two Sharpe ratios. Presumably there is some insight in Ledoit and Wolf's paper that makes their statistic superior to what I am about to suggest. Also, see stevo`americas comments on the question for references to some other sophisticated testing measures. But if what you're after is simplicity, then the following is still perfectly valid:

Let $R_{1,t}$, and $R_{2,t}$ denote returns on the two assets of interest. In this framework, I define the Sharpe ratio:
\begin{equation}
S_1 = \frac{\mathbb{E} R_{1,t}}{\sqrt{\mathbb{V} R_{1,t}}}
\end{equation}
For any random variable $X_t$ the sample mean is defined:
\begin{equation}
\bar{X} = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T X_t
\end{equation}
Let:
\begin{equation}
\bar{\sigma}_1 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T (R_{1,t} - \bar{R}_1)^2}
\end{equation}
A natural estimator for $S_1$ is:
\begin{equation}
\hat{S}_1 = \frac{\bar{R}_1}{\bar{\sigma}_1}
\end{equation}
I assume suitable regularity conditions on $R_{1,t}$ such that $\bar{R}_1 \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{E} R_{1,t}$, $\sqrt{T} \bar{R}_1 \overset{d}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}$, and $\bar{\sigma}_1 \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} \sqrt{\mathbb{V}(R_{1,t})}$ (e.g. weak dependence and suitably bounded moments). By Slutsky's theorem, these conditions are sufficient for:
\begin{equation}
\hat{S}_1 \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} S_1
\end{equation}
and note that by Cramer's theorem:
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{T} \bar{S}_1 = \frac{\sqrt{T} \bar{R}_1}{\bar{\sigma}_1} \overset{d}{\rightarrow} \mathcal N
\end{equation}
since the numerator is converging in  distribution to a Normal, and the denominator is converging in probability to a constant strictly greater than $0$.

So we have a CLT for our statistic. For the purposes testing a difference in two statistics, it is easier if our statistic can be phrased as a single sample mean. This is straightforward. Let:
\begin{equation}
Y_{1,t} = (\bar{\sigma}_1)^{-1} R_{1,t} ,
\end{equation}
where it is worth emphasizing that it immediately follows that:
\begin{equation}
\hat{S}_1 = \bar{Y}_1 .
\end{equation}
Incorporating the second asset, we now define:
\begin{equation}
d_t = Y_{1,t} - Y_{2,t} .
\end{equation}
The theory thus far is sufficient to show that under:
\begin{equation}
H_0 : S_1 = S_2 ,
\end{equation}
we have:
\begin{equation}
\bar{d} \overset{d}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0, \alpha) .
\end{equation}
So we've literally transformed the problem into testing whether a sample mean is equal to zero, with a CLT existing for the sample mean. If you think $d_t$ exhibits time-series dependence, then you will need to estimate $\alpha$ using a HAC estimator, or else you could just bootstrap the statistic. Both are likely to give you similar outcomes. If you aren't worried about time-series dependence then just estimate $\alpha$ using the sample standard deviation of $d_t$ over $\sqrt{T}$.